# Axios - Interceptors: prevent further handling by original caller

Tags: javascript, if-statement, promise, axios, xmlhttprequest

I have a succesful response interceptor for my Axios instance. Under certain circumstances I basicly want to prevent further execution of `.then()`'s and `.catch()`'s.

```
axiosExtended.interceptors.response.use(response => successHandler(response), error => errorHandler(error))

function successHandler(response) {
    const relativeRequestUrl = response.config.url;
    const relativeResponseUrl = trim(response.request.responseURL.replace(response.config.baseURL, ''), '/');

    if (relativeRequestUrl !== relativeResponseUrl) {
        // dont return anything to original caller. No then. No catch.
        router.push(relativeResponseUrl)
    }

    // get handled by original caller...
}
```

Comment: read this https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/583

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @felixmosh:

```
instance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  if (someCondition(response) {
    return new Promise(() => {});
  }
  return response;
});
```